# installing Apache Ant 1.8.4 on centos

Tags: java, apache, ant

I want to install `apache ant1.8.4` on my `centos` machine. I've read in the apache website but i didn't really understand how should i do tha. I didn't find the package on their website.
Is there any option to use the `yum install` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a way of installing Ant as a package. On the Apache Ant website, you do it manually. The tarball or zip provided has the entire Ant package installed. It's not that difficult:

- Unzip or untar it to a special directory like `/opt`. I install all third party stuff in `/opt` on my system. Everything in the zip or tarball will be under the `apache-ant-1.8.4` directory, so Ant will be under `/opt/apache-ant-1.8.4`.
- In your `.profile`, set `$ANT_HOME` to where Ant was installed (`/opt/apache-ant-1.8.4` in the above example. Then, add `$ANT_HOME/bin` to your `$PATH`.
- Or, my preference, symbolically link all programs under `/opt/apache-ant-1.8.4/bin` to the `/usr/local/bin` directory and put that directory in the front of your PATH. This allows you to put all specially installed executables in one directory that can be placed in your `$PATH`.

That's about it. If you have the Ant executable (It's a shell script on Unix/Linux/Mac, and a batch script called `ant.bat` on Windows) in your PATH, it should work.

You mentioned you didn't have the Java Development Kit (JDK) installed. This must be installed first since Ant is a Java program. There must be a CENTOS package for Java. If not, you can try http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp to download Java on your system.

Comment: Thanks I've already found a way to install the `jdk binary file`, from oracle website, and I've installed ant .I don't think that I'll need to add it to the `$PATH` because I need ant for Jenkins builds.

Comment: Is this for Jenkins? You can have Jenkins install Ant and its various versions automatically. Jenkins can also install the JDK automatically, but this takes a wee bit more setup since you must have an Oracle account to do this.

Comment: How can i do that ? And i have an oracle account.

Comment: Go into _Manage Jenkins_ -> *Configure System*. (`http://$JENKINS_URL/configure`). and go to the JDK section. Click on the "Add JDK" button. Give it a name, then select the _Install automatically_ checkbox. Select the version, and agree to the licenses agreement. You'll see the JDK appear in the dropdown list of JDKs when you configure a project. Go to http://sun.java.com and sign into the Oracle page on your Jenkins server. Don't sign out.

Comment: Actually, I just tried. If you go through http://java.sun.com, you can download the JDK without an account. If you go through http://oracle.com, you do have to have an account to download the JDK.

Comment: What about `ant` i saw there an option to install it automatically, I chose a version, and selected install automatically checkbox, i'd like to know how is it going to work ?
I've added a new node to jenkins and selected and in the Node Properties section the Tool Locations checkbox, than i chose the ant version which i configured, and provided it a path for the installation, i'd, i saw that the node was created but the Ant hasn'r been installed.
Any idea why ?

Comment: The automatic Ant installation is only for the MAIN Jenkins server. In the slave nodes, Ant and the JDKs must be manually installed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have jdk installed, you could do the following:

```
cd $HOME
wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.9.2-bin.tar.gz
tar xvfvz apache-ant-1.9.2-bin.tar.gz
In .bash_profile, add the following line
ANT_HOME=$HOME/apache-ant-1.9.2
PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin
. ./.bashrc_profile
ant -version ##you should see version of ant.
```

(updated to 1.9.2 for wget)

Comment: I don't have jdk installed... could you provide me please the commands for that?

Comment: try installing it as mentioned [here](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-install-java-16-in-linux.html)

Comment: I'm trying to instal the `OpenJDK` in centos 4.4 and i'm getting the following error :

`error: Failed dependencies:
        rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.i686
        rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.i686`

Comment: plz adjust the wget to 1.9.2 version